# Which packages write /etc/lsb-release and /etc/issue?

Tags: package-management

What packages write or replace `/etc/lsb-release` and `/etc/issue` in Ubuntu or Debian?

Comment: Can you explain, why you were interested in this? What was the problem you were working on?

Answer (score 5):

Install `apt-file`, and run:

```
apt-file update
apt-file search /etc/lsb-release
```

And..

```
apt-file search /etc/issue
```

This returns the list of packages that provide the specified file.

Here, we see that both of the files are provided by the `base-files` package.

Answer (score -1):

apt-file points at "base-files" just installs the original file, which is later on messed with all the time.

This link has a fact-based description.
http://deadmemes.net/2010/10/19/fear-and-loathing-in-debianubuntu-or-who-needs-etcmotd/

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.